# Why WildFly ignores filters defined in web.xml?

Tags: wildfly, web.xml, ear, wildfly-10

I have an application running on WildFly-10.1.0.Final. I deployed it correctly, but some entries of my `web.xml` are ignored.

This is a part of my `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>ExtProjectFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.raylloy.filter.ExtProjectFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>ExtProjectFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

When I use a jboss-5.1.0.GA this works fine, a new instance of my filter is created. But on wildfly-10.1.0.Final, my filter is ignored.

Is there a way to fix it? Is there something I need to add in `standalone.xml`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Similar setup works for me. Could you try moving the filter to the top and also check with generic pattern like <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> to see if you are reaching your filter.